# An example of a separable Banach sequence space in which the finite support sequences are not dense?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I am wondering if there exist examples of Banach (or Frechet) sequence spaces in which the set of all finite support sequences are NOT dense?

Comment: whatever you mean by "finite support sequences" in a Banach space X, you can consider the direct sum of X and the line generated by a hen.

Comment: @Pietro: I thought hens generated ellipsoids, not lines ...

Answer (score 9):

Probably the simplest example is $c$, the space of convergent sequences.  The closure of the finitely supported sequences is, of course, $c_0$, the space of null sequences.